# How can I deserialize a Celery canvas from json?

Tags: python, json, celery

It's easy to serialize a Celery canvas to json like so:

```
import json
from celery import Celery
from celery import chain

app = Celery()


@app.task
def add(a, b):
  return a + b


@app.task
def mult(a, b):
  return a * b


def main():
  canvas = chain(add.s(1, 2), mult.s(2), mult.s(2))
  print json.dumps(canvas)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

This produces:

```
{
    "chord_size": null,
    "task": "celery.chain",
    "subtask_type": "chain",
    "kwargs": {
        "tasks": [
            {
                "chord_size": null,
                "task": "__main__.add",
                "subtask_type": null,
                "kwargs": {},
                "args": [
                    1,
                    2
                ],
                "options": {},
                "immutable": false
            },
            {
                "chord_size": null,
                "task": "__main__.mult",
                "subtask_type": null,
                "kwargs": {},
                "args": [
                    2
                ],
                "options": {},
                "immutable": false
            },
            {
                "chord_size": null,
                "task": "__main__.mult",
                "subtask_type": null,
                "kwargs": {},
                "args": [
                    2
                ],
                "options": {},
                "immutable": false
            }
        ]
    },
    "args": [],
    "options": {},
    "immutable": false
}
```

But, it wasn't clear to me how to de-serialize this data back into a Celery canvas. I looked into `kombu/serialization.py` and `celery/security/serialization.py` but neither of those were the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To deserialize Canvas signatures you can pass a dictionary into the signature method.

```
import json
from celery import signature

serialization = json.dumps(canvas)
canvas = signature(json.loads(serialization))
```

Documentation: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.signature

Comment: That doesn't answer the question though. I want more than the signature, I'm looking for the topology of the tasks themselves.